# How to filter the output of pexpect

Tags: python, pexpect

In python pexpect, I want to filter the oupt. For example, in the below code I want only the date to be printed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pexpect,time
p=pexpect.spawn('ssh myusername@192.168.151.80')
p.expect('Password:')
p.sendline('mypassword')
time.sleep(2)
p.sendline('date')
p.expect('IST')
current_date = p.before
print 'the current date in remote server is: %s' % current_date
```

**Actual output:**

```
the current date in remote server is:
Last login: Thu Aug 23 22:58:02 2012 from solaris3
Sun Microsystems Inc.   SunOS 5.10      Generic January 2005
You have new mail.
welcome
-bash-3.00$ date
Thu Aug 23 23:03:10
```

**Expected output:**

```
the current date in remote server is: Thu Aug 23 23:03:10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`before` will give you everything since the previous `expect` call.

You could split the output on newline:

```
current_date = p.before.split('\n')[-1]
```

However it would be better to expect the prompt instead of sleeping 2 seconds:

```
p.sendline('mypassword')
p.expect('[#\$] ')
p.sendline('date')
```

Comment: ecatmur: That was a nice solution. Also thanks for pointing a solution to wait for the prompt.